# Aerospike - LDT Top Record Create Error

Tags: java, aerospike

I am getting the error when trying to put an item into the large list. I am using the following things in my project:

- Aerospike java client
- ldt-enabled set to true
- Following is the code where error throws up

  LargeList llist = client.getClient().getLargeList(new WritePolicy(), key, binName);

  llist.update(list);

Comment: I am working in support for Aerospike and I would advise against using LDT as this is not considered a fully mature component of the product.

Comment: I also have another question. I am planning to use a largemap and each map entry has list as its value against a key. Can I use largelist inside a largemap?

Comment: Solved the issue by upserting the value in the large list one by one instead of a value list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by upserting the value in the large list one by one instead of a value list.

```
for(Object listItem: java.util.list){
llist.update(Value.get(listItem))
}
```